# Bias of kernel density estimator

Tags: bias, kernel-smoothing

This question is related to a calculation on page 20 of Kernel Smoothing by Wand and Jones.

i) Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a density for a real-valued random variable, and assume that $f''$ exists, is continuous and square integrable, i.e. $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f''(x)^2\ dx < \infty$.

ii) Let the sequence of bandwidths $h=h(n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers that satisfies $\lim_{n \to \infty} h = 0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} nh=\infty$.

iii) Let the kernel $K:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a symmetric, bounded probability density function with finite fourth moment.

I wish to show that $$E \hat{f}(x;h) = \int K(z)f(x-hz)\ dz=f(x)+\frac{1}{2}h^2z^2f''(x)\int z^2K(z)\ dz+o(h^2).$$
where $\hat{f}$ is the kernel density estimate. If the above identity holds, it follows that the kernel density estimator is asymptotically unbiased. The first equality is clear, but the second one I find tough to show. We may expand $f(x-hz)$ in a Taylor series as
$$
f(x-hz)=f(x)-hzf'(x)+\frac{1}{2}h^2z^2f''(x)+o(h^2)
$$
and then calculate the integral as
\begin{align}
\int K(z)f(x-hz)\ dz&= \int K(z)(f(x)-hzf'(x)+\frac{1}{2}h^2z^2f''(x)+o(h^2)) \ dz \\
&= f(x)+\frac{1}{2}h^2f''(x)\int K(z)z^2 \ dz+\int K(z)o(h^2) \ dz
\end{align}

where we used that $\int K(z) \ dz=1, \int zK(z) \ dz = 0$. My trouble is thus to show

$$
\int K(z)o(h^2)dz = o(h^2)
$$
The problem is that the $o(h^2)$-term depends on $z$. We need to show that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\int K(z)o(h_n^2)dz }{h_n^2} =\lim_{n \to \infty}\int K(z)\frac{o(h_n^2)dz }{h_n^2}= 0
$$

which would be clear if we could pull the limit under the integral. This would be justified by the dominated convergence theorem if the $\frac{o(h^2)}{h^2}$-term was uniformly bounded in $z$, since $K$ is a probability density. But I do not see from where we could get such bound. Any ideas would be appreciated